# Serializar dados PHP

Tags: php

como eu posso serializar o array abaixo para salvar no BD?

[image: Serializar array]

Eu tentei serializar mas ficou assim:

```
a:2:{s:8:"produto1";a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Novo produto";i:1;s:1:"2";}s:8:"produto2";a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Bolo caseiro";i:1;s:1:"2";}}
```

Quero que fique algo do tipo:

```
produto1:Novo produto,quantidade:2;produto2:Bolo caseiro,quantidade:2;
```

E assim por diante, é possível?

Comment: `json_encode()` não server?

Comment: Kkkkkk que noob que eu sou, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar json_encode no array e salvar a string que ele gera.